# How to send role from ASP.NET Web API in token based authentication and set it in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

How can I add role to the response using asp.net identity when a user authenticates?

I am working on a project where I need to authenticate the user. I have built an API in ASP.NET and I'm using ASP.NET identity framework for authentication.

Now I need to know which user has logged in so I've assigned roles to users. I don't know how to send the role of the user along with the bearer token. I've looked for the solution but didn't find it.

Any help will be appreciated.

This is the code which is communicating with the API.

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var getTokenUrl = Wedding_Hall.AppSettings.TOKEN_URI;

    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", model.Email),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", model.Password)
                });

        HttpResponseMessage result = httpClient.PostAsync(getTokenUrl, content).Result;

        string resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(resultContent);

            AuthenticationProperties options = new AuthenticationProperties();

            options.AllowRefresh = true;
            options.IsPersistent = true;
            options.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(int.Parse(token.expires_in));

            var claims = new[]
                    {
                         new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.Email),

                         new Claim("AcessToken", string.Format("Bearer {0}", token.access_token)),
                    };

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "ApplicationCookie");

            Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(options, identity);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Login Attempt");
            return View("Login", model);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not an expert on this but... where are you storing each users role(s)? Are you using organizational id's (O365)?

Comment: The roles are stored in database. While registration I'm using asp.net identity to assign appropriate role.